# Nginx is only redirecting to port 8080

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a .net 8 solution multiple APIs and I'm using docker and Nginx to host the application. please find below the full details:

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
...

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "xxx.Api/xxx.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xxx.Api.dll"]
```

launchsettings.json

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true,
  "sslPort": 4430,
  "httpPort": 8080
}
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http{

    server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   domain;
        port_in_redirect off;

        location /api1 {
            rewrite             /api1(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass          http://api1:8080; 
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api2 {
            rewrite             /api2(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass          http://api2:8081; 
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - api1
      - api2


  api1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api1:latest
    container_name: api1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api1.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"


  api2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api2:latest
    container_name: api2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api2.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

API1 that uses port 8080 loads normally but API2 that uses 8081 get error 502 gateway error.
If I switch the port on those same projects than API2 loads normally and API1 stops loading.
I've been trying all kinds of stuff over last 2 days and nothing seems to work.
Those same projects with the same configuration were working perfectly when I was using .net 6 with the same nginx version, but when I upgraded the project to .net 8 it broke.
I need your help and suggestions. Anything will be helpfull.

Comment: Please do not post images of code

Comment: @Paolo just fixed it no problem

Answer (score 0):

Our you services work in one enveronment. Nginx resolve app1 and app2 directly need to use direct ports not external.

```
location /api2 {
                rewrite             /api2(.*) $1 break;
                proxy_pass          http://api2:8080; 
                proxy_http_version  1.1;
                proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header    Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
            }
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? I'm fairly new to nginx.

Comment: Check "docker ps" ports. What ports used api1 and api2?
Nginx nothing to do with it. You services(nginx,api1,api1) described in compose file work in one environment. In docker file for api1 and api2 you expose api on port 8080, therefore nginx resolve requests to app1:8080 and app2:8080 good.

Comment: the docker file expose every api on its own port I used only one example code here just to keep it brief.

Comment: docker ps - check expose apiX port and proxy_path to this port on nginx config.